# How to set CmakeLists path in product flavor for each Android ABI?

Tags: android, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I need to have a separate CMakeLists.txt for each Android ABI. I tried to use product flavor to set the path for CMakeLists.txt. But I am getting following error on running `./gradlew assembleDebug` or any other gradle command from command line.

> Could not find method path() for arguments [CMakeLists.txt] on object
>   of type
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ExternalNativeCmakeOptions.

Here is how I have set product flavor in build.gradle.

```
productFlavors {
    arm64_v8a {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
    }
    x86_64 {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                path "CMakeLists.txt"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE - I had initially named the files as "CMakeLists_arm64-v8a.txt" and "CMakeLists_x86_64.txt". But that was failing so tried same name.

How to fix this or is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Hi have you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot have `CMakeLists.txt` paths different for different flavors and/or ABIs, but you can use the arguments to add conditionals in your cmake script, for example like this:

```
flavorDimensions "abi"
productFlavors {
    arm64_v8a {
        dimension "abi"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "arm64-v8a"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DFLAVOR=ARM"
            }
        }
    }
    x86_64 {
        dimension "abi"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "x86_64"
        }
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DFLAVOR=x86"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can check this in your **CMakeLists.txt**:

```
if (FLAVOR STREQUAL 'ARM')
  include(arm.cmake)
endif()
```

But in your case, you can rely on the argument that is defined by Android Studio, and don't need your own parameter:

```
if (ANDROID_ABI STREQUAL 'arm64-v8a')
  include(arm.cmake)
endif()
```

Actually, you probably don't need separate **productFlavor**s at all, but rather use **splits** to produce thin APKs for each ABI.

Comment: Hello Alex. Would you mind checking this problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57285584/add-cppflags-from-flavor-and-buildtype-then-access-them-in-my-cmakelist), it is the same issue but could not make it work.

Comment: To get it to work, I personally had to use full quotes in the STREQUAL comparaison instead of single quotes.

So in my case
```
if (FLAVOR STREQUAL "ARM")
```
works, while
```
if (FLAVOR STREQUAL 'ARM')
```
does **not** works.