# Could not find method cppFlags() arguments() for arguments

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk, ndk-build

I am trying to use

```
std::function
```

But the compiler throws an error

```
Error:(50, 10) error: no type named 'function' in namespace 'std'
```

I have tried to modify the build.gradle file

```
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
    }
    cmake {
        cppFlags "-std=c++11"
        arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static"
        path 'src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
    }
}
```

But it doesn't accept arguments other than `path` and throws the following errors

```
Error:(28, 0) Could not find method arguments() for arguments [-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.CmakeOptions.
```

Please help me to be able to use

```
std::function
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to **@Alex Cohn** I was able to configure flags and arguments, and now my file looks like that

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags "-std=c++11"
                arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static"
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        /*   ndkBuild {
               path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
           }*/
        cmake {
            // cppFlags "-std=c++11"
            //arguments "-DANDROID_STL=gnustl_static"
            path 'src/main/jni/CMakeLists.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Do you have `#include <functional>` into your cpp source?

Comment: You might further add the `-DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11` to your arguments settings.

Comment: @vre, yeah I have tried, adding arguments doesn't work, it won't accept any arguments at all, can I set this arguments in CMAke file itself ?

Comment: Btw. there is a superfluous comma at the end of the arguments line. I guess that prevents those other options to be recognized. You use the comma only for separating different arguments.

Comment: @vre, you rigth however this is just a typo, I have accidently typed it while inserting the code

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are two entirely different blocks in **build.gradle** that are named **externalNativeBuild** (thanks, Google).

[One](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeBuild) is under **android** top-level block, and it specifies the path to native build script, **cmake** or **ndkBuild** (but not both).

The [other](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.1/com/android/build/api/dsl/ExternalNativeBuildOptions) can be used to specify, from gradle, some parameters for the native build. This block is usually a child of the **defaultConfig** block, but can also appear for *flavors* (see an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47361259/192373)).

These **externalNativeBuild** blocks can also have  **cmake** or **ndkBuild** children, but only the child that matches the **path** setting (see above) is relevant, the other is silently ignored.

The bottom line, split your block in two, and put each one in correct place in **build.gradle** hierarchy.

Comment: Very valuable information !! Thank you I will try to solve the problem now, at least I am able to set flags now.

Comment: I don't know what I would have done without your answer !! It works !! NOW IT WORKS !! I wonder where I can find the information provided by you ? I have read all official docs several times ! thanks, Google

Comment: *sad android noises*