# how android gradle pass build version to android mk

Tags: java, android, gradle, java-native-interface, android.mk

i have a android project which can build v2,v3 version

```
 productFlavors {
       

        v2 {
           
            versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionBuild}"
        }

        v3 {
            dexguard = false
            
        }
}
```

i want to use two version of native jni code for different  build version, v2,v3

so, i want to pass the v2,v3 productFlavors  to android.mk,
how can i do it? or, there is any way to know in android.mk which version (v2,v3) is build ,then it can build different version of jni code

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47361259/1524450   (in your case you would use `externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild` instead of `externalNativeBuild.cmake`)

Comment: thank u, mr Michael

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to do this

1.in build.gradle define a global variable `version`
2.assign `version` with different value in different flavor
3.check the `version` variable to use different android.mk

```
String version=""
productFlavors {
       

        v2 {
           
            versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionBuild}"
            version="v2"

        }

        v3 {
            dexguard = false
            version="v3"
            
        }
}

if (version=="v2") {    
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path "AndroidV2.mk"
            }
        }
    }else{
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                path "AndroidV3.mk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```