# Add cppflags from Flavor and BuildType then access them in my CmakeList

Tags: android, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I have this gradle:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            externalNativeBuild {
                cmake {
                    cppFlags "-DGENDEV"
                }
            }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This if condition works fine in my CMakeList file:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" MATCHES "GENDEV$")
    // true
endif()
```

I recently added [flavors](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) in my build like so:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "version"
        externalNativeBuild.cmake {
            cppFlags "-DFLAVOR_FREE"
        }
    }
    full {
        dimension "version"
        externalNativeBuild.cmake {
            cppFlags "-DFLAVOR_FULL"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have these checks in my CMakeList file:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" MATCHES "FLAVOR_FULL$")
    // full version
else()
    // free version
endif()

if("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" MATCHES "GENDEV$")
    // true
endif()
```

The first check is always false, thus every build is a FREE version! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have pasted your code into my (minimal) NDK project, and it did work as expected.  But couple of questions have popped up. *FIrst*, how do you choose the flavor to build? *Second*, what are the versions of Gradle, Android plugin, and Android Studio? Because, with the Canary latest, my CMake didn't work as I wanted. When I use the stable `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'`, `gradle-5.5-all.zip`, all is well.

Comment: I hope the update will do it

Comment: Thanks Alex. Please add this info as an answer and will accept as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is alright, but the Gradle plugin was too old to handle it correctly.

For me, same code worked with

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    }
}
```

This plugin requires Gradle 5.5.

Note that an easier approach to CMake integration could be to specify **arguments**:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    free {
        dimension "version"
        externalNativeBuild.cmake {
            arguments "-DFLAVOR=FREE"
        }
    }
    full {
        dimension "version"
        externalNativeBuild.cmake {
            arguments "-DFLAVOR=FULL"
        }
    }
}
```

This way, your `CMakeLists.txt` will be more readable:

```
if(${FLAVOR} STREQUAL "FULL")
    // full version
else()
    // free version
endif()
```

Or, you can choose to use `arguments "-DFLAVOR_FULL"` and `if(FLAVOR_FULL)`

Comment: I have added a supplemental answer that completes the solution of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I want to also point out that `MATCHES` is matching a regex expression. Thus, changing the following:

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" MATCHES "FLAVOR_FULL$")
```

to

```
if("${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}" MATCHES "FLAVOR_FULL") // without the $
```

helped solved the problem. Basically, the original condition means to match the "FLAVOR_FULL" text if it is at the end of the string such as "-DGENDEV -DFLAVOR_FULL". This won't match if the string is "-DFLAVOR_FULL -DGENDEV".